# devise before_action: Verify reCaptcha before a user is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up reCaptcha with Devise and I want to add a filter that checks if verify_recaptcha is true before allowing a user to be created. If it's false, the user should not be created.

I've tried to follow Devise's [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise) on how to do it, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I'm testing recaptcha in production mode too, and the general setup works and I can check if reCaptcha is true or false.

This is what Devise tells me to do in the RegistrationsController:

```
prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any actions you want to protect.

private
def check_captcha
  unless verify_recaptcha
    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
  end 
end
```

Didn't work. Im 100% sure the verify_recaptcha method works and it's not something wrong with the setup.

I've tried:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :check_captcha

  private
    def check_captcha
      if !verify_recaptcha == true
        flash[:recaptcha_error] = "Fejl. Husk at sætte flueben i at du ikke er en robot"
        signupuser_users_path
      end 
    end
```

end

But no luck. How would I do this? Where does devise normally handle validation methods to be run before a user is signed up??

Comment: I think in your controller you should put this `prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create]`  instead of  `before_action :check_captcha`, because I think you need this on only signup

Comment: Thanks. I eventually got devise's method to work with the code in my answer below

Comment: can you give me up-vote on my comment

Comment: I tried with prepend_before_action instead of before_action and it did not work. So I'd rather not. I don't think its a popular thing in here to upvote others because they ask for it. Stackoverflow is about solving the issues, and it did not solve my issue. Also from what I've read, the two methods are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work eventually by changing a tiny part of devise's method:

```
prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create] # Change this to be any actions you want to protect.

private
def check_captcha
  unless verify_recaptcha
    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    respond_with_navigational(resource) { redirect_to :back }
  end 
end
```

I guess what's behind devise is a little too advanced for me to roll with my own method, but a little tweak made an okay solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript validation

```
<%= submit_tag "Sign Up", :onclick => "return validatecaptcha();" %>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function validatecaptcha(){
        var captcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(captcha_response.length == 0)
        {
            // Captcha is not Passed
            $("#notice").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+"Captcha mandatory"+'</div>');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Captcha is Passed
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    if !verify_recaptcha
      flash.delete :recaptcha_error
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      resource.valid?
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Recaptcha verification failed, please try again.")
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
    else
      flash.delete :recaptcha_error
      super
    end
  end
```